# How many bits can each memory location hold?

Tags: architecture, cpu, computer-science, memory-address

I am having trouble understanding this question...

For a CPU with 28 address lines and 16 data lines, determined how many memory locations can be addressed by the CPU and how many bits each of these memory locations should be able to store.

How do you determine how many memory locations can be addresses by the cpu and how many bits each of the locations can store?

Comment: 2^28 memory locations and 16 bits per each?

Comment: I believe that it is 2^28 * 2^4 which would give you 2^32.